# Как реализовать прилипание к потолку и стенам и прыжки от них в проивоположную сторону в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю Аркаду, в Unity, где персонаж может прыгать со стены на стену, и с потолка на пол!
Мне с помощью урока по гравитации удалось, его заставить на пробел прыгать с потолка на пол и обратно, но как реализовть чтобы это происходило по кнопкам (стрелки или W,S,A,D, и как сделать чтобы он также прыгал со стены на стену, прямо а не под углом?
Вот как примерно должно быть!

[image: Вот как примерно должно быть!]

А вот как сейчас!

[image: А вот как сейчас!я]

Вот код! С помощью которого прыгает с потолка по пол и обратно!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Playerv2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Movement Speed
    public float speed = 30;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius = 0.3f;
    public LayerMask  whatIsGround;

    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    Animator _anim;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    private void Start ()
    {
        rb2d.gravityScale = 150f;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Гравитационные изменения
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded ())
        {
            rb2d.gravityScale *= -1;
            transform.Rotate (0, 180, 180);
        }    
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Горизонтальное движение
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.right * h * speed;        
    }
    public bool isGrounded ()
    {
        var collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);

        return collider != null;
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D co)
    {
        // Collided with a V?
        if (co.collider.name == "V")
        {
            // Reset Rotation, Gravity, Velocity and go to last Checkpoint
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            rb2d.gravityScale = Mathf.Abs (rb2d.gravityScale);
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius);
    }
}
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Искал и в Yandex и Google и на русском и на английском, но находит все не то.

Comment: На всех "стенах" и "потолках" стоят коллайдеры?

Comment: RiotBr3aker Да! На всей поверхности стоит Box и Polygon Collider2D

Answer (score 0):

Может немного глупо или с опозданием, но можно попробовать двигать не через rb2d.velocity, а просто используя изменения позиции :

```
public float PlatformSpeed = 0.1f;
float xPositiot = transform.position.x + (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * GetPlatformSpeed);
transform.position = playerPos;
```

А потом просто ограничить передвижение в игровом мире при помощи такого подхода (ну вместо цифры 7 значения ж будут ваши) :

```
 playerPos = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(xPositiot,-7f,7f),-7f);
```

PS: Это довольно глупый подход но точно рабочий, и я не называю эту реализацию хорошей,но она должна решить вашу проблему.
Удачи

Comment: transform.position.x + делать так плохо т.к. для физического движка это равносильно телепортации

Comment: да, но я написал что это не очень подход но он самый простой, мы же не знаем для каких целей это будет писаться. Вот в дополнение есть видео на ютубе где рассматривают способы как двигать объекты [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Bhy8ySbews)

Comment: подход далеко не глупый, если Вы понимаете что  Вы делаете

Comment: Я где-то допустил ошибку? Ибо вроде понимаю что да как, ибо подход простейший же.

Answer (score 0):

Стены, пол и потолок поместите на любой слой, отличный от слоя игрока.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class MoveCharacter : MonoBehaviour
{
public float Speed = 0.3f;
public float JumpForce = 1f;
public LayerMask GroundLayer; 

private Rigidbody2D _rb;
private BoxCollider2D _collider;

private bool _isGrounded
{
    get
    {
        var bndCenter = new Vector2(_collider.bounds.center.x, _collider.bounds.center.y);
        return Physics2D.OverlapBox(bndCenter, _collider.bounds.size, GroundLayer);
    }
}

private Vector2 _movementVector
{
    get
    {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        return new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    _rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    MoveLogic();
}

private void MoveLogic()
{
    if (_isGrounded) _rb.AddForce(_movementVector * Speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}


}
```